# Blackberry phonegap application prompts for credetials when server returns 401

Tags: iis, cordova, blackberry, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing blackberry application using PhoneGap. When in LogIn page if invalid credentials are provided by the user and server returns 401 error,blackberry is displaying a window asking for username and password.This is not happening in iOS and android.Can any one suggest how to suppress this prompt? I am using IIS as server and used MVC web api for developing service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like BB has issue with Unauthorized 401. try sending different codes like HttpStatusCode.BadRequest. should work.